# JSON.Stringify() returns undefined instead of text

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, forms, form-data

I am making a form that downloads the data the user puts into it. So far the file downloads, but instead of the user's input it returns

`[object Object]`

I tried using JSON.Stringify(). But it is returning a file with "undefined" inside it. Even though the console.log() is giving me `{username: "asdasd", password: "sdasdasd"}`.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(formData);
      var formDataString = JSON.stringify(FormData);
      // ... submit to API or something
      download(formDataString, 'json.txt', 'text/plain');
    };
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
      username: "",
      password: "",
    });
    function download(formDataString, fileName, contentType) {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      var file = new Blob([formDataString], {type: contentType});
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      a.download = fileName;
      a.click();
  }
```

My full code is viewable [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/nodejslesson/blob/master/front/src/App.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check lines 2 and 3 of snippet reported here, the answer is pretty simple: you're saying `JSON.stringify(FormData)` with capital **F** , while the `console.log` outputs `formData` with lower **f**

Variables are case-sensitive in JavaScript, so `FormData` is never defined (`undefined`), while `formData` is what you have correctly defined above, and `console.log(formData)` correctly outputs in the console the content of the variable.

Comment: I can't believe it was right under my nose this whole time. Thank you. I'll accept this as the answer in 6 minutes

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp can you imagine how many hours I wasted with similar errors? :)  Don't worry, it's awlays like this: it's under our nose but we never see it!
Personally, using IDEs such as WebStorm helped me a lot to avoid or identify mistakes like this.